# How to run multiple shell scripts from applescript in background

Tags: applescript

I am launching an a jar application from apple script.

```
do shell script quoted form of jvmpath & " -jar -XstartOnFirstThread -Dapple.awt.UIElement=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 " & quoted form of jarpath & " " & quoted form of parameters
```

The script keeps running till i quit my jar application.

But i am required to launch another application form shell script.

Since i am doing this in a Cocoa app i want to do this in the background.

Thus, can i launch multiple scripts in multiple instances of terminal (so that they aren't blocking one another).

Note: I tested it by running the command in two different terminal windows, works as expected.

Comment: if you don't want to wait end of 'do sheet script' command, you must redirect its output somewhere else, to a file or nowhere. for instance adding '< /dev/null' (without quotes) at end of you 'do shell' command will redirect output to no-where. then your script will not wait for completion, and it will keep running.

Comment: @pbell I came across the solution and have it as a backup. But the idea is to start two background processes. Doing so will allow me to get a call back to my cocoa app when the jar is exited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Technical Note TN2065](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2065/_index.html), specifically the answers to the questions "I want to start a background server process; how do I make do shell script not wait until the command completes?" and "I have started a background process; how do I get its process ID so I can control it with other shell commands?".

The AppleScript code to run two commands in the background would look like this:

```
set pid1 to do shell script command1 & " &> /dev/null & echo $!"
set pid2 to do shell script command2 & " &> /dev/null & echo $!"
```

The pid1 and pid2 variables will be set to the process ids of the two commands. You can later check whether the commands are still running by calling a function like this one:

```
on isProcessRunning(pid)
    try
        do shell script "kill -0 " & pid
        set isRunning to true
    on error
        set isRunning to false
    end try
    return isRunning
end isProcessRunning
```